# How do floating left on Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Tech-filter not floating left .col-md-8
How to!?
What is my mistake?

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row tech-list">
  <div class="title col-md-6">
        <h1>Rent Technics</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="breadcrumbs col-md-4 pull-right">...
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <small style="float:left">3279 technics</small>
      <div class="bt-group">
...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="bt-group pull-right">
...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-8 ">
     ...
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>

     ...
  </div>

  <div class="tech-filter col-md-4">
      <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            ...
        </div>
      </form>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't pick up filter block

[image: yellow block is filter]

Answer (score 0):

Try add div `row` or use a wider column `col-md-12` for `tech-filter`?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="tech-filter col-md-4">
        <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">
            ...
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

-- or --

```
<div class="tech-filter col-md-12">
</div>
```